# navigate() throwing error - react native

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, navigation, this

I am trying to sign out my firebase user, and in the `onPress` of the icon I am using to sign out I have a function that executes a command to navigate back to the login screen. The logout with `firebase.auth.signOut` is successful, I just get this red screen:

[image]

Here is my relevant code:

```
static navigationOptions = {
    headerTitle: 'Inventory Control',
    headerLeft: null,
    headerRight: (
      <Icon name={'exit-to-app'}
            onPress={() => { firebase.auth().signOut()
                              .then(() => { 
                                  this.leave();
                              })
                              .catch(err => {
                                Alert.alert(err);
                              })
                           } 
                    }
      />
    ),
    headerTitleStyle: {textAlign: 'center', flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#ddeaff', color: '#518dff', fontFamily: 'American Typewriter', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 20},
    headerStyle: {backgroundColor: '#ddeaff'}
};

leave = () => {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    navigate('LogIn').catch(err => {Alert.alert(err)});
}
```

No errors are caught, just the red screen. As far as I can tell the error is coming from the `navigate` call - the actual navigation to the `LogIn` page never happens, it just stays on the screen that I logged out on. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

**UPDATE**

I think it has something to do with using `this` inside the `onPress` inside the `navigationOptions` - possibly because `this` is referring to a scope outside of the component that it is in? How do I handle using `this`? When I comment out `const { navigate } ...` the error goes away, so it has something to do with `this.props.navigation` I believe (and `this`?).

**UPDATE**

I think I am correct about the `this` keyword, the below code produces an error:

```
....

headerRight: (
      <Icon name={'exit-to-app'}
            onPress={() => {
              //firebase.auth().signOut()
                //.then(() => { 
                  const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
                  navigate('LogIn').catch(err => {Alert.alert(err)});
                //})
                //.catch(err => {
                  //Alert.alert(err);
                //})
            }}
      />
    ),

....
```

The error is: `undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this4.props.navigation')`

Comment: What `react-navigation` version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There's been a recent update to `react-navigation` with other errors circulating, due to the recent update https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/releases

If you are using version 2.12.0 I suggest downgrading to  2.11.2 , till bugs are fixed.

Comment: thank you, i have `"react-navigation": "^2.11.2"` in package.json - is this correct...i removed the `^` and ran `npm install` and i am still getting the same error

Comment: just incase i tried upgrading to `2.12.1` same problem

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
      headerTitle: 'Inventory Control',
      headerLeft: null,
      headerRight: (
        <Icon name={'exit-to-app'}
              onPress={() => {
                firebase.auth().signOut()
                  .then(() => { 
                    //const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
                    //Alert.alert(Object.keys(navigation));
                    navigation.navigate('LogIn');
                  })
                  .catch(err => {
                    Alert.alert(err);
                  })
              }}
        />
      ),
      headerTitleStyle: {textAlign: 'center', flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#ddeaff', color: '#518dff', fontFamily: 'American Typewriter', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 20},
      headerStyle: {backgroundColor: '#ddeaff'}
    }
};
```

I had to use the `navigation` method that gets passed with `navigationOptions` to make the navigation.